# Please solve this error:

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm unable to start Main Activity by using Intent.The error I have mentioned in the end of this code. How can I solve this error?

The method startActivity(Intent) in the type Activity is not
applicable for the arguments (Intent)

```
package com.example.rishabhsintent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Intent extends Activity {
Button b;
EditText e;
TextView t;
SharedPreferences.Editor spe;
SharedPreferences sp;

public Intent(Intent intent, Class<MainActivity> class1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intent);
    spe = sp.edit();
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            spe.putString("Message", e.getText().toString());
            spe.commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.this, MainActivity.class));

        }//Error on startActivity;it says"The method startActivity(Intent) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (Intent)"

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
           }
          }
```

Comment: Please change you Activity name. It's really confusing now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about questioner directly asking.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty strange name for `Activity` you chose. Try to create `Intent` like this:

```
new android.content.Intent(Intent.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what @FD_ wrote, you're passing the startActivity() method a call to the constructor of your own class, which makes no sense: firstly, because constructor are not intended to be used that way, secondly because constructors return nothing. Simply change your class' name and declare a "real" Intent.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the name of the Activity. Intent is a reserved class of Android and shouldn't be used for your classes. In the line `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.this, MainActivity.class));` the name Intent is not unique and you must aware which class is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intenet = new Intent(Intent.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intenet);
```

Comment: No difference to the OP's code. This won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1st define your activity into your AndroidManifest.xml file

eg :

```
 <activity android:name="YourPackage.MainActivity">
 </activity>
```

2nd start your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Intent as a class name. It's a reserved class in android, otherwise android gets confused and thinks you're referencing an intent and not your class. It's best to chose a name that is unique.